# How to read a node value of string contains xml in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

i have a String in my page, String response.
 This String contains the xml content. Now i need to check the condition based on the response value. so i need to get the particular node value. For eg,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response version="1.0">   
    <Transaction mode="INTEGRATOR_TEST" channel="d225a9fefe3fbaf400fe43294aca000d" response="SYNC">                <Identification>
               <ShortID>463.4646.464.4463</ShortID>  
               <UniqueID>8a82944932c9db190132cee846be54d0</UniqueID>  
               <TransactionID>K8463</TransactionID>   
    </Identification>  
    <Payment> 
               <Clearing>   
                   <Amount>1000.00</Amount>      
                   <Currency>INR</Currency>  
                   <Descriptor>XX XCXXXXX</Descriptor> 
                   <FxRate>1.0</FxRate>    
                   <FxSource>INTERN</FxSource>  
                   <FxDate>2011-10-04 12:28:41</FxDate>   
               </Clearing>       
    </Payment>  
    <Processing code="DD.DB.90.00">  
              <Timestamp>2011-10-04 12:28:41</Timestamp>     
              <Result>ACK</Result>     
              <Status code="90">NEW</Status>  
              <Reason code="00">Successful Processing</Reason>     
              <Return code="000.100.110">Request successfully processed in 'Merchant in Integrator Test Mode'</Return>          <Risk score="0" />      
    </Processing>  
    </Transaction>
</Response>
```

So in that How to read a particular node? For eg how to read Status Node?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the XML Dom object.

Example here:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dom.asp

Comment: Come on man, is that really necessary?  You're spreading the link of site that attacks another.  Not really helpful.

Comment: I'm just trying to help make you aware of the difference between a good source such as the [w3c wiki](http://www.w3c.org/wiki) or [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM) which are regularly updated and accurate, and a bad source such as w3schools which is closed off to the community and often glaringly out-of-date.